# Android color rendering

Tags: android, colors, rendering

Given:

- an *@color* specified in RGB, no alpha
- a png that is filled with pixels at that same RGB value, no alpha
- a layout with the color as background and containing the image

Will the rendering always - *on a single given device* - be flawless? Or is there a possibility of some color difference between the image and the background?

Comment: There was some confusion with the question.  @Simon and I agree...If the image and background color contain the same RGB values they will appear the same on any device.  Now they may be different when comparing 1 device against another, but the question was whether the layout and the image would look the same on that device.

Comment: @spartygw I know, I misread the question.  Comment deleted. Yes!  At the lowest level, rendering of your layout and image is just pouring pixels into a bitmap.  The only way the OS knows how to set those pixels is from the RGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The color rendered on a device for an image filled with a given RGB value and a layout with the same value specified will be the same.  That is, you will not notice a difference between your image and the layout color.